# ExecutorService submit() - Execute in parallel (non-blocking)

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to run a task in parallel. I have tried the following:

In my constructor:

```
this.executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

then I add all the items I want to run in parallel to a list:

```
   Future<Map.Entry<Location, SomeData>> result = this.executor.submit(new Sender(entry));
   resultList.add(result);
```

Then I loop on that list and use the `get()` function of `Future` in order to execute each task - which appears to be blocking:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < resultList.size(); i++) {

        Future<Map.Entry<Location, SomeData>> result = resultList.get(i);

        try {
            logger.info("[Start] Task" + sendQueue.get(i).getKey() + "-" + i);
            entry = result.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            logger.error("Interrupted error", e);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            logger.error("Thread Execution error", e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Send Error", e);
        }

        if (entry == null) {
            logger.error("Telemetry Send Error");
            return;
        }

        logger.info("[Success] Task" + entry.getKey() + "-" + i);
    }
```

Sender call():

```
@Override
    public Map.Entry<Location, Data> call() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        return this.entry;
    }
```

I see that each task is executed after the other. I want to execute all tasks in parallel and make it non-blocking.

Any idea what I'm missing? Isn't it what the executor service used to do?

Comment: I don't understand why you invoke `awaitTermination`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the invokation to `submit` you need to invoke `awaitTermination`. In that way, you will give some time for the task to get executed until a time out defined by you is reached or the execution ends.
Then, you should be able to check the future results by invoking `get`.

Another option provided by the `ExecutorService` API is to call `invokeAll`which is a blocking operation that triggers all the tasks. I personally prefer the first option described above.

Update: Also, you didn´t show the `ExecutorService`configuration but I assume that you are assigning more than one thread to it. Otherwise, the executions will be sequential no matter what you do after the `submit`.

Comment: Hi, I updated my executor configuration. I assumed the `awaitTerimnation` is the MAX time to wait for each task before cancelling it.  So I already have it set, but I don't understand what's wrong with it and why my tasks are not executing in parallel.

Comment: `awaitTermination`will wait ten seconds for all tasks to be finished (or interrupted). If MAX_CPUS is bigger than one, tasks should be executed in parallel.

Comment: Oh, and you have to place `awaitTermination`after you have submitted all your tasks (not after initializing the executor service.

Comment: Thanks. a bit strange why but it seems like when my `MAX_CPS  = 2` it wasn't in parallel, when I raised it to `3` or greater, it did. It was just a configuration issue, but still don't understand why it didn't work at 2.

Comment: Also, the log [Start] is misplaced, Should be placed where the Thread.sleep() is. Myabe that is also confusing you.